# How should I make Java splash screen disappear when using SplashScreen-Image with SWT?

Tags: java, macos, swt

I've written an SWT application under OS X Sierra that takes a bit of time to start up, so I want to add a splash screen to make it clear that *something* is happening.  The `SplashScreen-Image:` [property in the Java Manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) seems perfectly suited to this.  This works to the extent that the splash screen image is shown, but the problem is that the image never disappears after the application main window finally appears.  I have tried adding

```
    final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
    if (splash != null) {
        splash.close();
    }
```

right before the dispatch loop starts, and still the splash image remains visible.  Neither the [Oracle demo code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java) for [the SplashScreen class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) nor the [class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) provide any useful guidance (IMHO) about what more I should do.

How *is* the splash image supposed to be dismissed or removed? What could I be doing wrong?

SOLUTION: Author did not really call `splash.close()`. See comments below first answer.

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21022788/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 You are right; it is exactly the same issue. I did search before posting, but evidently did it badly. My apologies. Thank you for spotting that – it is very helpful to read the discussions in the other issue.

Comment: Should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Possibly, but I have run out of close votes for today!

Answer (score 1):

I have application that use splash screen defined in the arguments of VM:

```
javaw -splash:splash.png   ...other params here...
```

The splash screen disappears automagically when first JFrame is set to be visible.

Probably this is not a solution to your exact problem, but maybe you can adopt this approach to make it work.

As to your solution, I have no experience with splash screens on OS X Sierra, neither with the one defined in manifest files, but are you sure, that this line that calls `splash.close();` really executes? Did you debug this code step by step?

Comment: I _thought_ the call to `splash.close()` was being executed, but it turned out it was not: the code right before the call was taking so long that I did not realize it never made it to `splash.close()` – I only assumed it must have been. Now that I fixed it so that `splash.close()` is indeed called, it turns out it hangs the entire application! My best guess at this point is that the SplashScreen AWT class does not work with SWT.

Comment: On another note, using the `-splash` command line argument shows the splash screen PNG image in the same way: it appears, but never disappears. I don't know why the behavior is different for me, but it could be either an OS X difference, or the fact I'm using SWT, or some other factor yet to be identified.

Comment: You can make a splash screen yourself from an undecorated JFrame and show it before initialization, then close it after initialization - but it will appear after VM start - few seconds, but is better than nothing. You could also file a bug in JVM, and maybe try using some other version of JVM.

Comment: @kryzstof I didn't mention it before, but I do know about that, and in fact it was the first thing I implemented. However, in my case, the splash window appears only a short moment before the main window of the rest of my application appears, which kind of defeats the purpose. IMHO the problem is the JVM start-up delay on OS X Sierra. I was hoping the JVM-based splash screen would be faster. Thank you for the suggestion, however.